# Mockk verify ask a function to run inside a coroutine body

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I was learning about Unit Testing with Mockk library, and the function i was testing is using a verify. So i run the test with coroutine test runTest{} but verify method ask me to run inside a coroutine body

[image: Function Error]

And, here is the code for function implementation :

```
override suspend fun getAnimeByAnimeId(animeID: Int): AnimeEntity? {
    return localDataSource.getAnimeByAnimeId(animeID)
}
```

So, i wonder what is wrong in here, why can't i call verify here even when the function is inside a coroutine body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coVerify` for verifying suspend functions with mockk. You have to make sure that you include the coroutines dependency in your tests (`testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:x.x"`).

Check the [mockk documentation on coroutines](https://mockk.io/#coroutines) for more information.